# They were married for 12 years before/when

Tags: past-tense, conjunctions, past-simple

In this particular sentence do *before* and *when* mean the same and can be used interchangeably?

> They were married for 12 years **before**/**when** they died/got divorced.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they do mean the same thing.

While they can be used interchangeably, the choice of conjunction may be influenced by what follows.

**They had been married for 12 years when they died in an accident.**

**When** here refers to a specific point in time.

**They had been married for 12 years before they decided to split up and go their own ways.**

**Before** here suggests that the decision was considered over a period of time.

However, these are nuances and reflect the writer's preferences rather than any rule.

Comment: Note that **had been** is more idiomatic than **were** (and we can't say "They were married for 12 years when...").

Comment: @KateBunting thank you! This is exacntly what I was wondering about. Do I get it right: in this particular sentence _when_ and _before_ are both correct with the past **perfect,** but with the past **simple** only _before_ is correct? _1) They were married for 12 years before **(only before)** they got divorced. 2) They had been married for 12 years before/when **(both)** they got divorced._

Comment: Yes, that's right.